# Get TypeScript type of member of readonly array element

Tags: typescript

I have a `readonly Pokemon[]` array named `PokemonData`.  Each element has a `name` member.  Is it possible to make a `type` that is a concatenated list of pokemon names?

```ts
interface Pokemon {
    readonly name: string;
    // ...
}

const PokemonData: readonly Pokemon[] = [{
    name: 'Pikachu',
    // ...
}, {
    name: 'Bulbasaur',
    // ...
}] as const;

type PokemonName = // TODO: should be 'Pikachu' | 'Bulbasaur'
```

I could easily do this if I had an array of just the names:

```ts
const pokemonNames = [ 'Pikachu', 'Bulbasaur' ] as const;
type ArrayType<T> = T extends readonly (infer U)[] ? U : never;
type PokemonName = ArrayType<typeof pokemonNames>;
```

I suspect, if this is possible at all, I need the object-property equivalent of my `ArrayType<T>` above and/or a function that takes in a `Pokemon` and returns its name.

```ts
// using a type approach (doesn't work)
type GetPokemonName<T extends Pokemon> = T['name'];
type GetPokemonNames<T> = T extends Pokemon[] ? GetPokemonName<T[/* something here */]> : never;

// using a function approach (may work, but I don't know how to convert it to a type)
function getPokemonName(pkmn: Pokemon) {
    return pkmn.name;
}
```

I also thought maybe the `ReadonlyArray<T>.map()` would be useful, but it just returns a string type.

```ts
const pokemonNames = PokemonData.map(p => p.name); // using 'as const' throws a compile-time error
type PokemonName = ArrayType<typeof pokemonNames>;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way Typescript will be able to see the names in the array as string literal types is if you remove the `: readonly Pokemon[]` type annotation; otherwise any `typeof` is going to be looking at the declaration of the `Pokemon` type rather than a more specific type inferred from the array's actual contents.

If you remove that annotation, then the names can be mapped to a union type:

```js
const PokemonData = [{
    name: 'Pikachu'
}, {
    name: 'Bulbasaur'
}] as const;

type PokemonName = (typeof PokemonData)[number]['name'];
```

The `[number]` maps the array type to its component type, and then `['name']` maps to a union of the string literal types associated with the `name` properties.

This isn't an ideal solution because removing the `Pokemon[]` type annotation means Typescript won't check that its contents are valid `Pokemon` objects. If you want that, you can write a helper function:

```js
function pokemon<K extends string>(obj: Pokemon & { name: K }): Pokemon & { name: K } {
    return obj;
}

const PokemonData = [
    pokemon({
        name: 'Pikachu',
    }),
    pokemon({
        name: 'Bulbasaur',
    }),
] as const;
```

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgAoHsDWEC26TIDeAUMmclBHACb4A2AnsiHDhAFzIDOYUoA5gG5iAX2LEYAVxAIwwfMgAOWXPgA8AaWQQAHpBDUu3XgIB8ACnQAjAFacM2PAQBkRZqw7ItIgJT2VTsiuhO5snN5EpOSUYJJQBNY2wmLECPg8aAH4ACJwYHDIALzIANpRZMqO+OYk5HWhngDkqMCYiAAWko0ANOXIvr11laogNX11LGHIjQBCknRWcFxwcT19A8QAushLyGkgPMLEYAyKKA4jAHIeRcjmJ2foMJlVILn5PiUgkjhW0JslRqTCCNTbCIA)

Comment: A late addition: From TS4.9 you can use the `satisfies` keyword to declare an inferred literal but still force it to be assignable to a type, in this case `const PokemonData = [[name: 'Pikachu'], {name: 'Bulbasaur'}] as const satisfies Pokemon[];`